# Get Token for Azure ADv2 Rest Api Protected

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I create an WebApi using visual studio and the wizard, for a protected api.

The result was an new application in the Azure Portal, and a configuration file jsonconfig (I am using netcore 2.2)

The web api is very simple a part of the code is

```
[Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
```

Now I am trying to get a token to call the api, using the next code

```
var msalConfig = {
        auth: {
            clientId: '83a8a6ee-afd5-41d3-92bd-2a6352cff7da', //This is your client ID
            authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/d7124a8f-3301-4c72-9231-4bb39d8b95a3" //This is your tenant info
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: "localStorage",
            storeAuthStateInCookie: true
        }
    };
```

and the calling

```
var requestObj2 = {

        scopes:["https://xxxxxx.com/Test2019/user_impersonation"]
    };



      var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);

function signIn() {
        myMSALObj.loginPopup(requestObj).then(function (loginResponse) {
            //Successful login
            showWelcomeMessage();
            //Call MS Graph using the token in the response
            acquireTokenPopupAndCallMSGraph();
        }).catch(function (error) {
            //Please check the console for errors
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

and at the end

```
function acquireTokenPopupAndCallMSGraph() {
        //Always start with acquireTokenSilent to obtain a token in the signed in user from cache
        myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(requestObj2).then(function (tokenResponse) {
            console.log(tokenResponse.accessToken);
            alert('autenticado');
            callMSGraph(graphConfig.graphMeEndpoint, tokenResponse.accessToken, graphAPICallback);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            // Upon acquireTokenSilent failure (due to consent or interaction or login required ONLY)
            // Call acquireTokenPopup(popup window) 
            if (requiresInteraction(error.errorCode)) {
                myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(requestObj).then(function (tokenResponse) {
                    callMSGraph(graphConfig.graphMeEndpoint, tokenResponse.accessToken, graphAPICallback);
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Everything works but the token generated when used in postman in the Authorization Header ="Bearer Token"

Does not work.

Please any advice on how to get the token.. :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way you get access token is correct. Replace the value of scopes by `scopes:["83a8a6ee-afd5-41d3-92bd-2a6352cff7da/.default"]` and try again.

If this still doesn't work, paste the error message here.

Here is a [complete example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi-v2) regarding calling the backend web api using access token.